# How to Export JTable data into a CSV File

Tags: java, swing, csv, jtable, export-to-csv

I am looking for a way to export a **JTable** with data to a **.csv file**. But I didn't find a good method to do that. It works and generates the **csv file**. But There is a problem. When there is data in a jTable column like this,

```
|column 1|column 2|
-------------------
|Java, C#|PHP     |
```

The result is,

```
column 1,column2,
Java,C#,PHP,
```

So the problem id there are only **2 columns** and **2 data columns** but for CSV file, there are **3 data columns**. When importing that CSV file to the Excel sheet it is completely wrong. Data went to different locations.

**So is there another way to do this in Java or any way to avoid this problem?**

Thanks for the help in advance! Best Regards.

**I use the following code.**

```
public void ExportToCSVfile(JTable table) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
            Writer writer = null;
            DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            int Row = defaultTableModel.getRowCount();
            int Col = defaultTableModel.getColumnCount();
            try {
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("file.csv"), "utf-8"));

                StringBuffer bufferHeader = new StringBuffer();
                for (int j = 0; j < Col; j++) {
                    bufferHeader.append(defaultTableModel.getColumnName(j));
                    if (j!=Col) bufferHeader.append(", ");
                }
                writer.write(bufferHeader.toString() + "\r\n");

                for (int i = 0 ; i < Row ; i++){
                     StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    for (int j = 0 ; j < Col ; j++){
                        buffer.append(defaultTableModel.getValueAt(i,j));
                        if (j!=Col) buffer.append(", ");
                    }
                    writer.write(buffer.toString() + "\r\n");
                }
            } finally {
                  writer.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't role your own, use an appropriate [CSV library](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+csv&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) - the requirements are more complicated then just sticking a `,` between values

Answer (score 1):

> So is there another way to do this in Java or any way to avoid this problem?

I don't know all the rules of a CSV formatted file but I believe for something this simple where a cell contains a "," you can just delimit the entire text of the cell.

So the ouput of your file should be:

```
column 1,column2,
"Java,C#",PHP,
```

This is easy to verify you just create a simple spreadsheet where the cell contains a comma and then you export the spreadsheet to a .csv file and check the format of the file in a text editor.

I think you can delimit all data with "..." even if it doesn't contain a comma but you will need to verify that.

So you need to modify your export code to include the delimiters.

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana, We are not here to write the code for you. What don't you understand about the suggestion? As a specific question if the suggestion is not clear. You are using a StringBuffer. All you need to do is append a double quote to the butter before and after the value you obtain from the table model.

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana, glad the suggestion helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Instead of CSV, I tried to export as an Excel file. I think this will also work. But I didn't try this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @HasithaMJayawardana  `But I didn't try this.` - why not? It's two extra lines of code from what you originally posted.